# XSL Matching and copying element names from two xml files

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm matching values to names from two source xml documents with the following xsl (thanks to plenty of help from others on this site). So this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>    
 <xsl:key name="kPhysByName" match="KB_XMod_Modules" use="Physician"/>              
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'InfBy')]">
  <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="document('profiles.xml')">
   <xsl:variable name="vMod" select="key('kPhysByName', $vCur)"/>
   <xsl:copy>
    <items>
     <item>
      <label><xsl:value-of select="$vMod/Physician"/></label>
      <value><xsl:value-of select="$vMod/XModID"/></value>
     </item>
    </items>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...matches these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<instance>
  <record>
    <InfBy1>Dr Phibes</InfBy1>
    <InfBy2>Dr X</InfBy2>
    <InfBy3>Dr Chivago</InfBy3>
  </record>
    <record>
    <InfBy1>Dr Phibes</InfBy1>
    <InfBy2>Dr X</InfBy2>
    <InfBy3>Dr Chivago</InfBy3>
  </record>
</instance>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <KB_XMod_Modules>
        <Physician>Dr Phibes</Physician>
        <XModID>60</XModID>
    </KB_XMod_Modules>
    <KB_XMod_Modules>
        <Physician>Dr X</Physician>
        <XModID>61</XModID>
    </KB_XMod_Modules>
    <KB_XMod_Modules>
        <Physician>Dr Chivago</Physician>
        <XModID>62</XModID>
    </KB_XMod_Modules>
</root>
```

...to produce this:

```
 <instance>
  <record>
    <items>
      <item>
        <label>Dr Phibes</label>
        <value>60</value>
      </item>
    </items>
    <items>
      <item>
        <label>Dr X</label>
        <value>61</value>
      </item>
    </items>
    <items>
      <item>
        <label>Dr Chivago</label>
        <value>62</value>
      </item>
    </items>
  </record>
  <record>
    <items>
      <item>
        <label>Dr Phibes</label>
        <value>60</value>
      </item>
    </items>
    <items>
      <item>
        <label>Dr X</label>
        <value>61</value>
      </item>
    </items>
    <items>
      <item>
        <label>Dr Chivago</label>
        <value>62</value>
      </item>
    </items>
  </record>
</instance>
```

However in this example the parent `<InfBy1>`, `<InfBy2>` and `<InfBy3>`tags are missing. I'm struggling to find a way of copying these elements over while maintaining the correct name so that I have:

```
<InfBy1>
  <items>
    <item>
      <label>Dr Phibes</label>
      <value>60</value>
    </item>
  </items>
</InfBy1>
<InfBy2>
  <items>
    <item>
      <label>Dr X</label>
      <value>61</value>
    </item>
  </items>
</InfBy2>       
...etc
```

Thanks for looking...

Comment: I think I can answer my own question. I've just found I can use `<xsl:variable name="localname" select="local-name()" />` and `<xsl:element name="{$localname}">` which seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `xsl:copy` instruction is useless in that context (root node of document with `'profiles.xml'` URI).

That leads to the actual answer: use `xsl:copy` instruction where the context is the matched element.

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'InfBy')]">
 <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
 <xsl:copy>     
  <xsl:for-each select="document('profiles.xml')">
   <xsl:variable name="vMod" select="key('kPhysByName', $vCur)"/>
   <items>
    <item>
     <label>
      <xsl:value-of select="$vMod/Physician"/>
     </label>
     <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="$vMod/XModID"/>
     </value>
    </item>
   </items>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>
```